# Let $A$ be an $n×n$ matrix such that $A^2=I_n$. Then $\mathrm{rank}(A) =n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $n×n$ matrix such that $A^2=I_n$. 
 Then $\mathrm{rank}(A) =n$.

prove it or give a counterexample

Comment: attempts ? definitions etc.

Comment: What do you know about the determinant of $A$?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $\operatorname{rank}(AB) \leq \min\{\operatorname{rank}(A),\operatorname{rank}(B)\}$.

Comment: sorry where dose the B come from?

Comment: What I have stated is a general fact about any pair of matrices $A,B$ that can be multiplied, which can be applied to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can observe that since $A^2=I_n$, $A$ is invertible. Then, you can use the fact that if $B$ is an invertible matrix, then $rank(AB)=rank(A)$